# Show filed categories depend on doktype

Tags: typo3, tsconfig

with `TCEFORM.pages.categories.disabled = 1` I can disable the field categories for all doktypes. how can i disable the field for only one choosen doktype?

I have checked and tried the tsconfig-wiki, but I have not gone forward with that.

Answer (score 0):

you might use a typoscript condition. (Typoscript conditions are available in page-/user-TsConfig too.)

```
[page|doktype = 4,5]
TCEFORM.pages.categories.disabled = 1
[global]
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you. Mhh. I found out now that something like this

```
TCEFORM.pages.starttime.types.4.disabled = 1
TCEFORM.pages.categories.types.4.disabled = 0
TCEFORM.pages.categories.types.4.config.treeConfig.rootUid = 87
```

works for the doktype "shortcut".

I have set an own doktype with the number 116 and nothing from the code before works. I have been copied from here (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/PageTypes/Index.html)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: maybe your definition of the new pagetype comes later than your TSConfig. On the other hand: you should [define the list of editable fields](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8-dev/Types/Index.html) when you define your new pagetype in the TCA